# Project facet Java version 1.7 is not supported

Tags: java, eclipse, project, facet

When i update my java I found the issue "Project facet Java version 1.7 is not supported"
 To resolve this issue follow the steps.

1. Go to Ecllipse , right click on your project folder
2. select the properties
3. now select Project Facets ,here you will see java, click on the version and change the higher version to lower or as per your requirement .

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You need to check what type of JRE is there installed in your IDE,

[image: JRE]

Answer (score 4):

I had also encountered the same problem a while ago when upgrading from Java version 1.6 to 1.7. To resolve this I followed below steps.

1. Right Click on the Project on Project Explorer and click on Properties.
2. Navigate to Java Build Path > “Libraries”
3. **Delete any conflicted libraries which have red cross mark on the icons.**
4. **Check & edit if necessary the JRE System Library Jars.**
5. Navigate to Project Facets and select the required java version.

Source: https://tipandtech.wordpress.com/2013/09/13/error-project-facet-java-version-1-7-is-not-supported-in-eclipse/

Try them if you have not found the solution yet.

Shishir

Comment: Looks like someone copied your answer here, with no mention of StackOverflow anywhere, bit weird: http://tipandtech.wordpress.com/2013/09/13/error-project-facet-java-version-1-7-is-not-supported-in-eclipse/

Answer (score 4):

Double click the Tomcat server->run time environment->installed jre->select jdk 1.7

Answer (score 3):

I've just had the same thing. My solution was to remove the 1.6 JRE in Installed JRE's and tick the Java 1.7 one.

This can be found in Window --> Preferences --> Java --> Installed JRE's

Just as Boopathi says.

Answer (score 0):

Change the jre pointed by your server(tomcat or anything...)
point to a JDK instead of JRE

Answer (score 0):

Check for the version of JDK in Window --> Preferences -->Java compiler and then set the same JDK in  Window --> Preferences -->Project Facets -->Java

Answer (score 0):

1.Window Menu -> Preferences
2.On the left, select Server -> Runtime Environments
3.Highlight *The server you want for your project* and select the “Edit…” button
4.On the “Edit Server Runtime Environment” dialog, change the JRE to be a Java 
7 JDK or JRE.
5.Rebuild your project and the error should go away.

Answer (score 0):

For me the Java 17 appeared in Project facet after the following :

1- Window > Preferences > Installed JREs > Add JDK 17 then select it

2- Installed JREs > Execution Environment > Select JavaSE-17 > on the right side check the JDK 17

Answer (score -3):

When I ran into this same issue, I resolved it by changing work space.