# Dynamic Web Project - Project Facets not displaying CDI as a project facet

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, cdi, linux-mint

I'm trying to add CD,I as a project facet to a Dynamic web project. But when clicking on the project facets view there is **no CDI option in the Project Facet list as you can see**:

[image]

I tried following [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19832348/project-facet-java-version-1-7-is-not-supported) in where they said to erase possible conflicting jres, and also the suggestions in here which [recommends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19832348/project-facet-java-version-1-7-is-not-supported) checking the installed jre's, my view of installed jres is:

[image: intalled jres]

I'm at linux mint so I'm also attaching a screenshot of the dir /usr/lib/jvm, in case you guys see any anomaly in it and also it seems my       java version is okay:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you installed JBoss Tools?

Go to **Help** -> **Eclipse Marketplace** find **JBoss Tools** **for your version** of Eclipse (To check version of eclipse go to **Help** -> **About Eclipse**)

[image: JBoss tools in eclipse marketplace]

Then select plugin you need

[image: Plugin need]

**UPD**

And also check Runtime Environments (window -> preferences)

[image]
[image]

**Eclipse should be restarted after installation**

Comment: The issue for me was that I had selected both "Apache Tomcat" and "jre_1.8.0..." in my _Targeted Runtimes_ list. Once I de-selected the latter, the _Dynamic Web Module_ option showed up in _Project Facets_.