# Java 1.7 not an option in Eclipse Project Facets

Tags: eclipse, version, facet

I am trying to use JDK 7 with my Java project.  JRE 7 is installed:

```
[Macintosh-2:~] Moby% java -version
java version "1.7.0_79"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
```

In Eclipse, I select the compiler Java 1.7:

[image]

and Java JRE 1.7 is installed:

[image]

But I get a facet version mismatch.  In project facets, I cannot even choose Java 1.7:

[image]

Why does Java 1.7 not display in facets?

I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19832348/project-facet-java-version-1-7-is-not-supported), and it does not help.

Comment: Is this a maven project by any chance?

Comment: No.  Maven is not used in this project.

Comment: What build system are you using? I'm betting the build file specifies source and/or target = 1.6.

Comment: Also, I couldn't help but notice that you referred to "JRE" 1.7 in your question multiple times. Please note that you need the "JDK", not the "JRE" if you want to compile code. JRE is just the runtime. JDK includes the compiler.

Comment: I have not specified a build system yet.  It's a new project and I am just trying to define some basic settings.  JDK 1.7 is installed.

Comment: What is output of the following command? (run in terminal): `/usr/libexec/java_home`. Whatever the output of that command is, make that your Installed JRE location instead of what you have in your screenshot (`/Library/Java/Home`).

Comment: What is the output of `/Library/Java/Home/bin/java -version`? Is that a path to a `1.6` jdk?

Comment: @Asaph That worked (`/usr/libexec/java_home`).  I updated Eclipse and all is good. Please move your last comment to answer.  Thank you!

Comment: On my system, JDK 1.7 was installed to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home`, not `/Library/Java/Home`.

Comment: @Asaph I flagged the comment that should be answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configured path for your `jre7`: `/Library/Java/Home` is actually pointing to your jdk6 installation. Change `/Library/Java/Home` to whatever the output of this command is: `/usr/libexec/java_home`.